# VBA MsgBox 'Liability Disclaimer'?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to include a MsgBox in a macro so when the document opens, the user has to check/click an "I Agree" button in order to continue and view the contents (and if the user clicks "Cancel" the document contents don't appear)?

This is what mocked up initially:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    rsp = MsgBox("I Agree", vbOKCancel)
    If rsp = vbOK Then
        MsgBox ("OK button")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Cancel button")
    End If
End Sub
```

I know it's not right, I just don't know what to refine. I also don't know how to make it appear as soon as someone opens the document.

UPDATE:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

rsp = MsgBox("[blahblahblah] I Agree", vbOKCancel)
If rsp = vbOK Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Else
    MsgBox ("You may not view document without agreeing to terms.")
End If
End Sub
```

The MsgBox still doesn't appear when opening the document though. And I still need to make the contents invisible if the user clicks 'Cancel'.

Comment: Yes, there is. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I usually do. I do not use a `Msgbox`. The reason is very simple. Sometimes I need to show lot of information in the `Disclaimer`. However if you still need to use a `MsgBox` then adapt it from below.

Do this

Insert a `UserForm` as shown in the image below. Place a `Textbox` and two `CommandButtons`. In the properties of the `Textbox`, make it multi line and scroll-able (Vertical only). Name the `CommandButtons` as shown in the image. Also change the `Textbox` `.Locked`property to `True` so the text in the `Textbox` is read-only at runtime.

[image]

Next, place this code in the `UserForm`

```
Const sLiabMsg As String = "Blah Blah Blah. Your Disclaimer goes here"

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    bAllow = False
    TextBox1.Text = sLiabMsg
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    bAllow = True
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Next insert a `Module` and paste this one line in it

```
Public bAllow As Boolean
```

Next in the `ThisWorkbook` code area, paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

    UserForm1.Show

    If bAllow = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet1.Activate
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Close (False)
    End If
End Sub
```

And you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
rsp = MsgBox("I Agree", vbOKCancel)
If rsp <> vbOK Then
  Application.Quit
Else
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```